# SQL Query: Retrieving records based on criteria in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

#### The Setup

I'm using a SQL Server DB to track various cases in production at a manufacturing environment.  The database has two tables:

1. *Status Table*: this tracks the status of those cases, with one of the columns containing an integer code that represents the cases status.  All cases with codes greater than 0 are "in production" while those with codes less than or equal to 0 are either "complete" or "canceled".
2. *Log Table*: this tracks what changes have happened to a particular case and when those changes happened.  The "what" aspect is captured both as a string and as a code.  The "when" is a datetime field.

#### The Problem / Task / Question

I would like to query all cases that are in production *AND* any cases that have been completed or canceled ***within the past two days***.  In the log, I have a datetime column and a code specific to both cancelling or completing a case.  I assume the query would maybe `JOIN` any cases from the log that have either of those codes and have datetimes within 48 hours prior of now.  But I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this.  The first part of my query (to get cases that are in production) is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM test.dbo.status WHERE status > 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

***UPDATE***
To clarify, two things:

1. I would like the query to return all of the columns in the *status table* for records that match the criteria above, not just the ID or something.
2. The table structures:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[status](
       [serial] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
       [type] [varchar](50) NULL,
       [commit_date] [date] NULL,
       [sent_to_prod] [date] NULL,
       [target] [date] NULL,
       [sent_to_mfg] [date] NULL,
       [status] [int] NULL,
       [notes] [bit] NULL,
       [hold] [bit] NULL,
       [canceled] [bit] NULL,
       [priority] [bit] NULL,
       [vendors] [varchar](150) NULL,
       [rework] [varchar](50) NULL,
       [created_on] [datetime] NULL,
       [modified_on] [datetime] NULL
   )

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[log](
       [serial] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,
       [action] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
       [who] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
       [time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [code] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
   )
   ```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the tables structure.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear...  For a case to be included, it has to be in production, OR have been completed or canceled within the past two days?  Or it has to be in production AND ALSO have been canceled or completed within the past two days?  Sounds like the former to me.

Comment: @mdoyle The former is correct.

Comment: One last thing--if a case is canceled or completed, its record remains in the status table?

Comment: Then OCary's answer is correct, once the table and field names are adjusted.

Comment: @mdoyle I think it's almost there, but not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you didn't provide any structure, I'd start with something like.

Query 1:  number of records returned will be the number of matching records from LogTable

```
SELECT StatusTable.ID, LogTable.When, etc etc etc.
FROM StatusTable INNER JOIN LogTable
  ON StatusTable.ID = LogTable.ID
WHERE StatusTable.status > 0
  OR (LogTable.WhatCode = 97   --Assumes 97 is your desired code.
  AND LogTable.When >= dateadd(hh, -48, GetDate()))
```

**Added**

Query 2: Use a sub query instead of a join to get desired IDs from LogTable.  (you could also look at the `EXISTS` operator instead of `IN`)

```
SELECT StatusTable.ID, StatusTable.otherField, etc etc
FROM StatusTable
WHERE StatusTable.status > 0 
  OR StatusTable.ID IN (SELECT LogTable.ID FROM LogTable WHERE LogTable.WhatCode = 97   --Assumes 97 is your desired code.
      AND LogTable.When >= dateadd(hh, -48, GetDate()))
```

Comment: Sorry about not providing the structure.  I updated the question.  Your answer, though, seems like it wouldn't return any rows, because cases with `StatusTable.status > 0` (meaning they're in production and not canceled or complete) would never *also* have codes saying that they were canceled or complete (via your `AND` statments)

Comment: See updated query.   criteria OR (other criteria and other criteria)

Comment: I think there is a problem with the `OR` or the `JOIN` portion of the query your provided.  Although the `AND` statement looks correct - I'm getting dozens of returns for each case.  The number of returns actually corresponds to the number of log records for that case (regardless of if they are associated with the code specified in `WhatCode`.

Comment: Here's my implementation if it helps: `SELECT [production_report].[serial]      
    FROM [production_report] INNER JOIN [log]
      ON [production_report].[serial] = [log].[serial]
    WHERE [production_report].[status] > 0
      OR ([log].[code] = '[G008]'  
      AND [log].[time] >= datediff(hh, -48, GetDate()))`

Comment: After troubleshooting a little, I find that the `OR` statement doesn't do anything - leaving it or dropping it or modifying it doesn't change the return...

Comment: I meant dateadd, not datediff.  Updated post to include a second query option, and fixed dateadd vs datediff. Queries both written from memory and not tested, if there are issues with the OR, I'd bet the datediff() isn't quite right, or your code is G008 not [G008]GAH!

Comment: Query 2 with dateadd made all the difference! Thanks!